# RewriteRule to change underscores to dashes only on the first directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know there are alot of questions already on this website related to the subject of turning underscores into dashes but i just couldn't find the right one.

Here's my problem, i only want to turn underscores into dashes in the first directory. And only when this directory is followed by a integer.

For instance:

www.mywebsite.com/**new_york**/8989/test-url/

has to become:

www.mywebsite.com/**new-york**/8989/test-url/

I dont want to have dashes in all directories because i'm using functions who need to have underscores.

What would be the right way of doing that? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_([^/]*)/(.*)$ /$1-$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```